# optional parameter in the output file with snakemake

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake, optional-parameters

Would it be possible to have a wildcard that could be empty in the output file and in the same time, the rule can be run by calling the rule name? By calling the rule name, the wildcard should be set as empty automatically. This is what I am trying to achieve.

A simplified example rule:

```
rule a:
    input: "csv.file"
    output: "output{kw,.*}.png"
    params:
        kwargs = lambda wc: f'--{wc.kw.strip("_")}' if wc.kw.strip("_") \
             else ""
    shell: "example.py {input} {output} {params.kwargs}"
```

can I call rule a to generate output.png?

Answer (score 0):

No, not with any standard means. If a rule contains a wildcard, it has to be specified via commandline and can not be called by the name anymore. (AFAIK there is also no way to pass a wildcard value to `snakemake` via CLI).

Personally I think this is a good design choice:
This way, any execution of e.g. the `rule a` are equal, distinguishable and intentional. A default value could make it more difficult to distinguish whether an execution was intended to run the workflow witout wildcard (i.e. the default value) or with an empty wildcard (which is equal but not identical to the default value).

Depending on your use-case, you could either implement a `rule all` which calls your rule and specifies the wildcard, or you could use rule inheritance to create a `rule a_default` which create a parallel rule with a wildcard default value:

```py
rule a:
    input:
        "csv.file",
    output:
        "output{kw,.*}.png",
    shell:
        "example.py {input} {output}"

# Option 1
# A rule which depends on rule a and executes it using the intended default value
rule all:
    input:
        "output.png",
    default_target: True

# Option 2
# A second rule which mirrors the behaviour of rule a but implements a default value
use rule a as a_default with:
    output:
        expand(rules.a.output[0], kw=""),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! These all make sense. My real case is a bit more complicated. I have an optional parameter for the example.py, this optional parameter is supposed to be reflected in the output file name (see my edit in the question). With option 1, can I still specify the wildcard as non-empty value? Or that could work by changing the default_target=False?

Comment: With option 1 you get a new rule which simply calls `rule a` in the background and sets the wildcard value `kw=""` , so your `lambda wc` function for `param` will still work. Note that this is a completely different rule, you could also call it differently. It is **not** a default value per se. What `default_target: True` does is, that whenever you call snakemake without a rule or files specified, it will run this rule.
With option 2 the wildcard is removed from the rule, so any instances of the `kw` wildcard for `rule a_default` will no longer work.

Comment: If snakemake cannot take the default of kw as empty in this case, does this mean the output line of the above rule equals to output: "output{kw}.png"

Comment: For `rule a_default` the `output` is "output.png". The `kw` wildcard get's filled with an empty string `""` as value.